# Get text directly inside a tag in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have some HTML that looks like:

```html
<dt>
  <a href="#">Hello</a>
  (2009)
</dt>
```

I already have all my HTML loaded into a variable called `record`. I need to parse out the year i.e. 2009 if it exists.

How can I get the text inside the `dt` tag but not the text inside the `a` tag? I've used `record.search("dt").inner_text` and this gives me everything.

It's a trivial question but I haven't managed to figure this out.

Comment: Note also that there are in fact two text nodes inside that `dt` (unless you parsed the HTML using the `noblanks` option): the first text node is `"\n  "` before the `<a>`, and the second text node is `"\n  (2009)\n"` after it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get all the direct children with text, but not any further sub-children, you can use XPath like so:

```
doc.xpath('//dt/text()')
```

Or if you wish to use search:

```
doc.search('dt').xpath('text()')
```

Comment: The methods above give you a NodeSet of [`XML::Text`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Text.html) nodes; you may want to use `at_xpath` (or just `at`) to get a single result, and then call the `.content` or `.text` methods on that node to get the text as a string from it.

Answer (score 12):

Using XPath to select exactly what you want (as suggested by @Casper) is the right answer.

```
def own_text(node)
  # Find the content of all child text nodes and join them together
  node.xpath('text()').text
end
```

Here's an alternative, fun answer :)

```
def own_text(node)
  node.clone(1).tap{ |copy| copy.element_children.remove }.text
end
```

Seen in action:

```
require 'nokogiri'
root = Nokogiri.XML('<r>hi <a>BOO</a> there</r>').root
puts root.text       #=> hi BOO there
puts own_text(root)  #=> hi  there
```

Answer (score 5):

The `dt` element has two children, so you can access it by:

```
doc.search("dt").children.last.text
```